# laravel 5.6 menu table how to link different page sections

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.6

Someone recommended me to create a menu table schema that i could link to different parts of a page and the menu table structure is:-

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('menus', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('parent');
            $table->enum('type', ['section', 'static', 'article', 'url']);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and these are the other tables structure.

```
statics: id, title, image, content
sections: id, title, description 
widgets: id, type[artcles, static, video, gallery], page[section to appear], ordering[smallint], articles[list, optional, video, gallery, code]
articles: id, title, image, content, section_id
```

what i wanted is to create a website with lots of pages and the homepage have different small sections like 'about us' 'what we do' 'our services' 'our staff' etc and when i click on read more link of those sections to go to the specific page of that part.

my questions is how i could make relations in models of that tables and what view blade pages i should create? and i want widgets to be static and dynamic as well.

Answer (score 0):

did you mean something like this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <h3>Navbar With Dropdown</h3>
  <p>This example adds a dropdown menu for the "Page 1" button in the navigation bar.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that is part of my question and how i could make relationship on models of those tables? what view pages i should create,  how i can make different widgets sections like top 10 popular articles, and static widget to include sections page. etc